# Cancel a mysql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to cancel a mysql query?

I have the problem that I submit a query which is very time-consuming because of a mistake. And now I can't make a new query because the server is working and working...

Or is there a way to stop all queries in a database or in a table.

For your information I am using phpMyAdmin (MySql).

Comment: warning, you can compromize your database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `KILL` statement : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html

Answer (score 30):

In phpMyAdmin, go to home page > Status; you'll see a list of your MySQL processes and you have a Kill link for each of them.

Comment: Where is the status button exactly? I can't seem to find it. Version 4.4.15.5

Comment: As I said, it's on Home page > Status, so click on the Home button in the left navigation panel, then you should see Status as one of the top menu items.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @Gobbin Glad to help!

Answer (score 18):

Probably your phpMyAdmin will be stuck showing the "Searching" message. What you can do is to open another tab / open a MySQL session with the console and do the following:

Look for all the processes running:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

And then kill that specific thread with the `KILL` command:

```
KILL <thread_id>;
```

Resources:

- [SHOW PROCESSLIST page in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-processlist.html)
- [KILL page in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html)

Comment: this is a better answer

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, you can't even get to phpmyadmin even on a new tab.

If you have access to the environment via command line,

1) log into mysql
`mysql -u yourusername -p`

2) `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

3) `KILL <thread_id>;`

Comment: You can open phpmyadmin in someother browser. and Status->processes->kill the process that shows your SQL Query

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

[Post in Mysql Forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,111006,111011#msg-111011)

This will teach you to test your queries before just throwing them into a page.  EXPLAIN PLAN is your friend.

Comment: +1 for explain, although persons asking this question are more than likely to not know how to read an Explain plan

Comment: Agreed, but if you're going to be doing these things it's a good idea to learn.

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes if the database server is not responding because of a too long query** and:

- the ***phpMyAdmin* is stuck showing the "Loading..." message**...
- you **can't log into MySQL server with appropriate permissions** or if so but the`SHOW PROCESSLIST` command in CLI **is not very useful** because of for example too big amount of started processes...

then, **the fastest option might be to restart the server**, which **stops all queries in a database**:

```
service mysql restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

---

**This is not the safest option**, because in some cases **the interrupted queries may cause inconsistency of data** in the database..., **but sometimes it may be the best solution**.